# Laravel, getting result by parent and childs

Tags: laravel

I'm working on small project using Laravel latest version, i have two models Building and Apartment
and i have created a relationship between the two models as you can see in the bottom.

I would like to get the result in hierarchy way, like that.

```
building_number x
      apartment_number x
      apartment_number y
      apartment_number z

building_number y
      apartment_number x
      apartment_number y
      apartment_number z
```

This is my models :

```
<?php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Apartment;

class Building extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function apartment(){
        return $this->hasMany(Apartment::class);
    }
}
```

//

```
<?php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Building;

class Apartment extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];
    
    public function building(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Building::class);
    }
}
```

My controller function

```
public function index()
{
    $apartments = Apartment::with('building')->get();
    return response()->json($apartments);
}
```

my result now :

```
[
   {
      "id":1,
      "apartment_number":"1",
      "building_id":1,
      "created_at":"2020-08-03T08:46:36.000000Z",
      "updated_at":"2020-08-03T08:46:36.000000Z",
      "building":{
         "id":1,
         "building_number":"1"
      }
   }
]
```

Comment: what are you doing to get that current result? and how is this different from your last question?

Comment: @lagbox  firstly i thank you for your quick answer, i have updated my question by adding my controller function.
the last question was about how to get the parent and childs. 
and this one i would like to know how can a get the data in hierarchy way as i described in my question 
Thank you

Comment: np and makes sense ...  mrhn's answer will load the relationship in the structure you are looking for, you want to query the parent and load the children as he has done in that example

Comment: @lagbox thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want it in that hierarchy, simply just do the inverse. Where you query buildings and include all the underlying apartments.

```
public function index()
{
    $buildings = Building::with('apartments')->get();
    return response()->json($buildings);
}
```